# My Concerns about Spring-Batch that you cant actually multi-thread/read in chunks while reading items

Tags: spring, batch-processing, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I was trying to batch simple file. I understand that I couldnt multi-thread it. So at least I tried to perform better while increasing the chunks param:

```
@Bean
    public Step processFileStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("processSnidFileStep")
                .<MyItem, MyItem>chunk(10)
                .reader(reader())
   ....
```

My logic needs the processor to 'filter' our non valid records.
but than I found out that the processor not able to get chunks.. but only one  Item at a time:

```
public interface ItemProcessor<I, O> {

    O process(I item) throws Exception;
}
```

In my case I need to access the database and valid my record over there. so for each Item I have to query the DB(instead of doing it with bunch of items together)

I cant multi-thread or make my process perform better? what am I missing here? It will take too long to process each record one by one from a file.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From past discussions, the CSV reader may have serious performance issues.  You might be better served by writing a reader using another CSV parser.

Depending on your validation data, you might create a job scoped filter bean that wraps a Map that can be either preloaded very quickly or lazy loaded.  This way you would limit the hits on the database to either initialization or first reference (repectively), and reduce the filter time to a hashmap lookaside.

Comment: Thanks for your response. but still beside of performance issues what other thread-safe side effects I might get??

Comment: The thread-safe side effects depend on your code.  Spring-batch is, ultimately, plain old java.

There are four successful patterns for multithreading processes presented in the spring-batch manual.

In this case, the design driver appears to be the performance limit of the CSV reader.  Until that is resolved, there is no point to considering multithreading.

With that said, here is how I would approach this problem:

Step 1 - Shard the original file using plain old text processing, creating (N) files that can be processed in parallel
Step 2 - parallelized step with taskexecutor per file,

Comment: Could you elaborate within the answer on your second approach? (parallelized step with taskexecutor per file) thank you.

Comment: It's all one approach.  Step 1 is to shard the original file into multiple files that can be processed independently.  Since a CSV file is just text, you don't need a CSV reader to do this, just the ability to separate lines of text.

Comment: Step 2 in the job implements the mechanism from http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/scalability.html section 7.1 , with one thread per sharded file created in step 2.  `<step id="loading"> <tasklet
    task-executor="taskExecutor"
    throttle-limit="20">...</tasklet>
</step>`

Answer (score 0):

In the Spring Batch chunk-oriented processing architecture, the only component where you get access to the complete chunk of records is the `ItemWriter`.

So if you want to do any kind of bulk processing this is where you would typically do that. Either with an `ItemWriteListener#beforeWrite` or by implementing your own custom `ItemWriter`.

Comment: Gotcha. And what happens when I use ItemStreamReader and FlatFileItemReader(inside) while setting chunk size which bigger than 1 and defining   taskExecutor. is it really reading from file multithreaded ?

Comment: Yes, but `FlatFileItemReader` is not thread-safe. Another possible approach is http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/springBatchIntegration.html#asynchronous-processors

Comment: Why would I care about Thread-safe in the scenario ? I dont care about roll-back in my case. is there any risk records might be called twice by different  threads?